# How to do Web Scraping using php, curl for web pages having infinite scroll and has ajax calls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, web-scraping

Some website have infinite scroller and loads the information with the pagination using AJAX. I want to scrape the web data with the code I am using in PHP and curl. I am newbie in scraping data from web pages.

Here is the code I am using to scrape the web page and get the data:

```
<?php

function curlUrl($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $results = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $results;
}

$restaurant = array();
function returningXPathObject($item) {
  $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument();
  $xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item);
  $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom);
return $xmlPageXPath;
}

$restaurantUrl = curlUrl('restaurants page url');

$RestPageXpath = returningXPathObject($restaurantUrl);

// new XPath DOM object
$title = $RestPageXpath->query("//h4[@class='store-name']");

if ($title->length > 0) {
  // For each restaturant
  for ($i = 0; $i < $title->length; $i++) {
    $restaurant['title'][] = $title->item($i)->nodeValue;
  }
}

var_dump($restaurant);
```

I get array of 10 restaurants.

I have tested this code and it works fine, but only gives 10 results but the web page has more than 10 results and once the AJAX calls are made in pagination, we get more results after scrolling down.

I have checked the developer tools and the network tab as well.

When i see the ajax calls made , and after clicking the preview i get

markup:"

I want to know how to make the markup show and also when i copy into my text editor i get get the whole data.

So should i everytime copy and paste to my editor and then do something like file_get_contents ?

Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

A cURL request just returns the server's initial response (whatever that may be, HTML, plain text, XML, JSON, a file, anything basically). It doesn't emulate a browser environment. Therefore, no javascript which is on the page will get executed when the page is requested via cURL - there's no environment in which it can execute.

That means you can't "scrape" anything but the initial response. No content that's loaded by ajax can ever be returned to you using a cURL request to the overall page. In order to get the extra content, you'd have to make a cURL request directly to whatever URL is being accessed by the original page in its javascript ajax methods. Of course there's no telling whether this will be feasible or not, and it may just return JSON rather than HTML. If it turns out that you can get the JSON, then you could use it to build your own markup and display the data that way.

Comment: When i echo out the url , i get and empty array on the ajax call url url/ functions/searches.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=england&search=Home+Tutors&where=shttre+7th+Phase&catid=1234&psearch=&prid=&page=3

Comment: @coold sorry I don't quite understand. Are you saying that `functions/searches.php...etc` is the URL of the ajax call and that you called this URL using cURL via PHP?

Comment: yes, this is the URL. .com or .org is not allowed in the comments by stackoverflow

Comment: @coold and what would you expect the URL to return (if not an empty array)? Did you check you didn't get any kind of error response (e.g. 404, 401, 500 or something)?

Comment: I have tried file_get_contents($url) as well. didnt helped. as well as used CURL

Comment: @coold that's not what I asked. Please answer my questions, if you can.

Comment: It should return the html content and i am not getting any error like 404,401,500.

Comment: @coold you are testing for HTTP errors using something like `$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` I assume?

Comment: yes i get 200 ok in the network tab, but the array is empty

Comment: what should i try now?

Comment: @coold not in the network tab - that's where your overall page is being loaded. Totally irrelevant. If you're making a cURL call to `searches.php`, you need to check the server's response to that call, by using the code I posted in my last comment. insert it just after `$results = curl_exec($ch);` and echo the value of $httpCode

Comment: output is given as 200

Comment: ok then the next possibility is that your parameters are wrong / or are just a combination that happens to return no results. Either that or the server-side code can detect that you're not making a request from within the intended website and therefore declines to return anything, but doesn't error.

Comment: Eactly, i think the data for the website is very very crucial for websites and it may detect that if its not call from their origin itself, it will not allow to get the data in any format. Let me know how would they have implement, using which technology?

Comment: I've no idea, there are several ways they could do it. But it's irrelevant - you can't spoof your origin (unless you want to get into some sort of hacking, which I don't advise). So if that's how it's being blocked, there's not really any way round it. As I said in my answer (which I think you should accept, as it's pretty much turned out to be true), it's very difficult, if not impossible, to scrape ajax-based web pages.

Comment: Okay, thanks, ill advise my clients accordingly, if they are willing to hack..:P, but wouldnt recommend it though..:)